# ServiceNow: All cloned tickets have one user's name in the history regardless of who might have added notes

Tags: servicenow

We have recently discovered this issue in our testing environment. All the cloned tickets (from production to development) have the requester's name in the Notes/Activity section even though some of the notes have been added by the fulfiller in production. If i create a new ticket in development, it works as expected and shows the correct name in the history. Its only the cloned tickets seem to have the issue.

We are using Tokyo version.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes funny things can happen in a clone. I have never seen this exact issue before, but I have seen other things just as strange. I would double check all my clone settings, and then try repeating the clone. If it is reproducible then I would open a case with ServiceNow.